# How to create a Mapping Table in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-forms, python-2.7

Consider i have 3 tables (User, Designation, Department). I have created Department table with Designation as manytomanyField(), so i know a map table Department_Designation is created and data will be auto populating in this table, when data is fed in Department Table. Now i need a Map between this  Department_Designation Map table and User table, so that i can relate the user to his Department and designation, how can i create that relation?. Is that approach a right way. Please do advice and suggest better way if any, with examples and documentation.
I am using python 2.7, Django 1.3, MySQL5.5 on windows.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation on [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but i would like advice on database design, I have tables called People, Roles, People_Login, Department, Designation

Consider people is a collection of Student and employes, if its a employee i want to mention his/her department & designation,
and based at login i want to check their role and direct to their respective pages or functions, but if Employee i would direct to their respective pages based on their designation. Can you please help me on that...